# Cómo paralelizar una operacion entre columnas apareadas de dos filas diferentes con NumPy

Tags: python, pandas, algoritmos, matrices, numpy

Lo que quiero mirar es ***si para dos posiciones/fila*** de una matriz numPy, ***para cada posición columna correspondiente, tienen el mismo valor***, y devolver la cantidad de columnas comunes o un listado de las posiciones comunes.

En mi caso concreto en realidad trabajo con booleanos (a 0 y 1) y compruebo los que estén a true.

He sabido implementar el código sin utilizar iteraciones de numpy y sin exprimir el verdadero potencial para lo que está hecho, y me gustaría optimizar la función ya que se llama muchisimas veces y realentiza el algoritmo.

El código que quiero optimizar es el siguiente:

```
#Devuelve array de posiciones comunes
def buscarProblemasComunes(self,user2):
        #Posiciones de las filas que voy a comparar       
        posOwner = self.userPosOwner    #Posicion fila 1
        posUser  = user2                #Posicion fila 2


        #Array provisional donde almacenaré las posiciones de las columnas comunes que existan entre ambas filas
        #self.matrizDatos es la matriz numPy sobre la que voy a trabajar
        arrayProvisionalPos = np.empty([self.matrizDatos.size],dtype=int)


        #Recorrido de cada columna de la matriz
        i = 0
        #Recorrido del tamaño del array provisional
        j = 0


        #Obtengo el tamaño de las columnas de la matriz numPy
        while i < self.matrizDatos.shape[1]:
                #Aqui digo que si la columna i de la fila 1 contiene lo mismo que la columna i de la fila 2 inserto la posición en nuestro array
                if(self.matrizDatos[posOwner][i] == 1 and self.matrizDatos[posUser][i] == 1):
                        arrayProvisionalPos[j] = i
                        j = j + 1
                i = i + 1

        #Aqui creo un array final con el tamaño real del array de posiciones comunes y muevo lo del provisional al array final
        #Este array es el que devolveremos.
        #En caso de querer obtener solo la cantidad de problemas comunes, devolvería J
        arrayPosComun = np.empty([j],dtype=int)
        i = 0
        while i < j:
                arrayPosComun[i] = arrayProvisionalPos[i]
                i = i + 1

        return arrayPosComun
```

Mi objetivo se trata en optimizar este algoritmo y poder exprimir al maximo la eficiencia de numpy en esta iteración, pero estoy bastante atascado y no logro darle otra perspectiva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas ningún tipo de bucle. Puedes hacer comparaciones booleanas entre filas, que se realizarán vectorialmente.

En el enunciado de tu pregunta pides encontrar elementos entre dos filas que sean iguales. Esto se lograría con:

```
iguales = array[fila1] == array[fila2]
```

El resultado será un array de booleanos, que tendrá `True` cuando hay elementos iguales entre ambas filas, y `False` cuando no. Es sencillo convertir eso a una lista de índices como la que tú necesitas:

```
indices = np.where(iguales)[0]
```

Eso te obtiene los índices de los elementos que son `True`.

Tu implementación en cambio no detecta los elementos iguales entre filas, ya que para que fuera así la línea que hace la comparación debería ser:

```
if self.matrizDatos[posOwner][i] == self.matrizDatos[posUser][i]:
```

En lugar de eso lo que haces es mirar los elementos en los que **ambas filas tienen un 1**. Si realmente es esto lo que querías hacer, también puede lograrse con la siguiente comparación vectorial numpy:

```
unos =  (array[fila1] == 1) & (array[fila2] == 1)
```

En este caso se usa `&` en lugar de `and`, por una razón un tanto técnica: numpy ha redefinido el operador `&` para que haga una operación booleana vectorial, mientras que `and` no puede ser redefinido porque no es un operador, sino un *keyword*. Las expresiones a ambos lados del `&` deben ir entre paréntesis, pues el operador `&` tiene menor precedencia.

En resumen, y por dar un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable, esta sería mi implementación de la clase y un caso de uso:

```
import numpy as np

class Clase:
  def __init__(self, matrizDatos, userPosOwner):
    self.matrizDatos = matrizDatos
    self.userPosOwner = userPosOwner       

  def buscarProblemasComunes(self, user2):
    posOwner = self.userPosOwner    #Posicion fila 1
    posUser  = user2                #Posicion fila 2

    # Caso de buscar elementos iguales
    booleanos = self.matrizDatos[self.userPosOwner] == self.matrizDatos[user2]
    # Caso de buscar donde ambas tienen unos
    # booleanos = (self.matrizDatos[self.userPosOwner] == 1) & (self.matrizDatos[user2] == 1)
    return np.where(booleanos)[0]
```

Ejemplo de uso, para ver que funciona:

```
>>> matriz = np.random.randint(1,5, (6, 10))
>>> matriz
array([[3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3],
       [4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1],
       [1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2],
       [1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3]])
>>> c = Clase(matriz, 0)
>>> c.buscarProblemasComunes(1)
array([1, 3])
```

Efectivamente, los elementos 1 y 3 de las dos primeras filas son iguales. Fíjate que si hubiéramos detectado si ambos son 1 el resultado habría sido sólo `array([1])`

### Edit

Si los elementos de la matriz son booleanos, la expresión puede ser aún más simple. Esta sería una posible implementación:

```
import numpy as np

class Clase:
  def __init__(self, matrizDatos, userPosOwner):
    self.matrizDatos = matrizDatos
    self.userPosOwner = userPosOwner


  def buscar(self, user2):
    return np.where(self.matrizDatos[self.userPosOwner] 
                    & self.matrizDatos[user2])[0]
```

### Edit2

Respondiendo a un comentario, si se buscan los elementos que en la primera fila sean 1 y en la segunda sean 0, desde el punto de vista del álgebra de Boole esto sería un `fila1 AND NOT fila2`.

Debido a que `not` no puede ser sobrecargado por numpy para funcionar vectorialmente (por ser un *keyword* y no un operador), han sobrecargado en cambio el operador `~` , por lo que la sintaxis sería:

```
  def buscar(self, user2):
    return np.where(self.matrizDatos[self.userPosOwner] 
                    & ~self.matrizDatos[user2])[0]
```

Comment: Gracias por la explicación, como bien has visto he errado al explicar el funcionamiento ya que lo que quiero ver son los casos en que ambas columnas estan a unos (en realidad representa una matriz de booleanos). luego pruebo tu implementación y calculo los tiempos nuevos para comprobar su mejora.

Comment: y si lo que quiero es vectorizar esta expresion? `if(self.matrizDatos[posUser2][i] == 1 and self.matrizDatos[posOwner][i] == 0)` O sea todo igual que lo de antes pero cambiando true true por true false

Comment: Gracias, eso acabo de ver, si puedo reformular la pregunta para corregir las erratas que he metido comentame como se hace para limpiarlo porque no encuentro que pueda reformular la pregunta, si consideras que debe rehacerse una nueva la haré (Tengo aun poca experiencia con las normas de stackoverflow y prefiero pedir consejo)

Comment: Puedes pulsar el enlace "editar" debajo de la pregunta, y modificarla como consideres, aunque ten cuidado de no introducir cambios tan drásticos que entonces la respuesta carezca de sentido...

Comment: @AlfonsoSoriaMuñoz Tengo curiosidad por la ganancia en velocidad, por favor comparte resultados :-)

Comment: Hola, me he puesto a calcular lo que gana de velocidad pero estoy viendo que no me genera resultados coherentes. depurando un poco mas compruebo que lo que me devuelven las funciones que he modificado me devuelve siempre un array de 64... mi matriz MxN tiene alrededor de 10.000X700 valores, estoy pensando que al realizarse operaciones vectoriales, solo itero sobre los 64 primeros valores sobre N... no se como hacer un bucle vectorializado... sobre todo por que si este programa se ejecuta sobre otro ordenador de tam de cada registro diferente(en vez de 64, 32) no sabría generalizarlo..

Comment: En conclusion, para una matriz de tamaño mayor a 64 que siempre sera el caso, hay que iterar usando esa operacion, pero no sabría muy bien como optimizarlo, o en otro caso, como usar la gpu para esa operacion, ya que imagino sera mejor que las operaciones del procesador multimedia...

Comment: @AlfonsoSoriaMuñoz No encuentro sentido a que sólo te funcione para 64 elementos. Numpy no tiene problema en hacer funciones vectorizadas sobre miles de elementos. Sin duda tienes algún bug en el código no imputable `numpy`. Por favor, abre otra pregunta y pon el código que estás usando (si no puedes poner los datos reales con que trabajas, haz un código que genere datos aleatorios, pero del tamaño apropiado para mostrar el problema que encuentras, supongo que con 500x500 sería suficiente)

Comment: estoy depurando el codigo para ver el estado de las variables previo al return, te comento con lo que sea, muchas gracias por todo. De momento "booleanos" lo veo bien y del tamaño que deberia ser, voy a ver que hace el np.where para ver si es el punto donde falla

Comment: okey, disculpa mi confusion, esta todo correcto, al parecer habia negado a user2 en vez de a owner(ejemplo edit2) y me daban cosas incoherentes y depurando me he hecho mas cacao por mirar donde no era, de momento a primera vista parece funcionar ya bien, y se ha reducido en 10 el coste total! (Lo que antes me tardaba intervalos de entre 30-60 segundos ahora ronda entre los 0.5, 5 segundos o_o muchisimas gracias, veo mas futuro a lo que ando haciendo, que, ya por desquitar curiosidades tiene que ver con recomendadores de problemas para jueces en línea.

Comment: hola, he abierto una nueva pregunta sobre matrices de python de una duda rapida pero que no encuentro en google, no se si sabrías también sobre lo que pregunto, un saludo! :)